# Chapter 0/Roman numerals

Tags: numbering, chapters, roman-numerals

I'm using the `book` document class, together with `subfiles` and `fancyhdr`. For pedagogical reasons, my document starts with Chapter 0.   I've managed to get the headers formatted as I want, with one notable exception:  there's no roman numeral 0!

Using

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\Roman{chapter}}}
```

makes the headers all roman (e.g., "Chapter VI") -- but leaves a blank for the Chapter zero number.   I tried an `\ifnum` statement in the main file, but it doesn't seem to recognize a statement like

```
\ifnum\value{chapter}=0
```

Nor do explicit `\renewcommand{\thechapter}` statements in the `subfiles` seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: There is no zero in the Roman numeric system. Using any other numeral is inconsistent.

Comment: Yes I know. The question is how to get around that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\ZeroRoman` as defined below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\ZeroRoman}[1]{% 0 + \Roman
  \ifcase\value{#1}\relax 0\else% Chapter 0
  \Roman{#1}\fi}% All other chapters
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ZeroRoman{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}% To start chapter numbering from 0
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapter{Last chapter}

\end{document}
```