# How to make a custom counter style work with enumerate references?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, enumitem

I'm trying to use the ZeroRoman style from [Chapter 0/Roman numerals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211414/). I also have a type of list that should be numbered under the chapter when being referenced. I get a `Missing number, treated as zero` error.

Here is an mwe:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\ZeroRoman}[1]{% 0 + \Roman
  \ifcase\value{#1}\relax 0\else% Chapter 0
  \Roman{#1}\fi}% All other chapters
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ZeroRoman{chapter}}

\newlist{test}{enumerate}{2} 
\setlist[test]{label=\arabic*., ref=\thechapter.\arabic*}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}

\begin{test}
\item Blah \label{label}
\end{test}

\ref{label}

\end{document}
```

How do I avoid this? I'm guessing `\thechapter` is being called in the preamble somehow, where the `chapter` counter isn't defined yet?

Comment: You can delay the expansion with `ref=\noexpand\thechapter.\arabic*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass on a token such as `\thechapter` unexpanded (i.e., without accessing the value) using `\noexpand`. The expansion will be performed by the next macro that receives the token. This can prevent issues with values that are not yet available.

MWE for this case:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\ZeroRoman}[1]{% 0 + \Roman
  \ifcase\value{#1}\relax 0\else% Chapter 0
  \Roman{#1}\fi}% All other chapters
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ZeroRoman{chapter}}

\newlist{test}{enumerate}{2} 
\setlist[test]{label=\arabic*., ref=\noexpand\thechapter.\arabic*}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\begin{document}
\chapter{}

\begin{test}
\item Blah \label{label}
\end{test}

\ref{label}

\end{document}
```

[image]